# printf printing my variables in the wrong order

Tags: bash

printf is printing my variables in the wrong order and newline isn't working. after iterating on various printf statements, it still doesn't working and i'm not quite sure what's wrong.

this is my current code:

```
cat ~/data/quotes.csv | while IFS=, read author quote; do
author_s=$(echo $author | cut -d'"' -f 2) # removes quotations - e.g. turns "Jonathan Kozol" to Jonathan Kozol 
printf "$quote\n\t~$author_s"
done | sort -R | tail -1 # print one random line from quotes.csv
```

this is my output (i'm also not sure what's causing the error):

```
-bash: printf: `w': invalid format character
    ~ Jonathan Kozol"Don't compromise yourself. You are all you've got."
```

however, i'd like to end up with something like this:

```
"Don't compromise yourself. You are all you've got."
    ~ Jonathan Kozol
```

also, when i try printing the variables $author_s and $quote on separate lines

e.g.

```
printf "$quote\n"
printf "$author_s"
```

author doesn't print

The first part of `quotes.csv`:

```
"Author","Quote"
"Thomas Edison","Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration."
"Yogi Berra","You can observe a lot just by watching."
"Abraham Lincoln","A house divided against itself cannot stand."
"Johann Wolfgang von Goethe","Difficulties increase the nearer we get to the goal."
"Byron Pulsifer","Fate is in your hands and no one elses"
"Lao Tzu","Be the chief but never the lord."
"Carl Sandburg","Nothing happens unless first we dream."
"Aristotle","Well begun is half done."
"Yogi Berra","Life is a learning experience, only if you learn."
"Margaret Sangster","Self-complacency is fatal to progress."
"Buddha","Peace comes from within. Do not seek it without."
```

Comment: You do understand that your qoute and author will be on separate lines, so if you print a one random line, it will print _either_ an author name _or_ the quote?

Comment: @TedLyngmo what is the dash for in `\n-`? also, i've tried your code and it only prints the quote

Comment: @KamilCuk right, LOL. oops

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks so much, but still only the quote is printing :/ i should also mention that even when i try printf "$quote\n", it doesn't a blank line after the quote

Comment: @TedLyngmo perhaps it's something to do with my csv file - its still only printing quotes for some reason. thank you for your help!!

Comment: @TedLyngmo https://gist.github.com/JakubPetriska/060958fd744ca34f099e947cd080b540

Comment: @cookiestarninja I moved the gist file into the question. Not everyone can reach that site.

Comment: `printf` doesn't add an automatic newline to the end like `echo` does. This means that unless you add one yourself (at the end of the format string), the first part of the next entry (i.e. the quote) will be printed directly after the end of the last entry (i.e. the author). I'm pretty sure that Jonathan Kozol didn't say "Don't compromise yourself. You are all you've got." (that was Janis Joplin) so you're seeing parts of two different entries stuck together because of a missing newline.

Comment: Anyway, OP you want: `shuf -n1 quotes.txt | while read ....`

Comment: @KamilCuk Brilliant. Are you going to add an answer or can I "steal" that in my answer? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `printf` should contain the *format string*. Your particular format would be `"%s\n\t~ %s\n"`:

- The first `%s` is the actual quote
- `\n\t` a newline and a tab
- `~ %s\n` a tilde, the author and a newline

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r author quote
do
    author="${author%\"}" # remove first "
    author="${author#\"}" # remove last "
    printf "%s\n\t~ %s\n" "$quote" "$author"
done < quotes.csv
```

In order to select a random quote you could use [`shuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf):

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -n +2 quotes.csv | shuf -n1 | while IFS=, read -r author quote
do
    author="${author%\"}" # remove first "
    author="${author#\"}" # remove last "
    printf "%s\n\t~ %s\n" "$quote" "$author"
done
```

Here `tail -n +2 quotes.csv` skips the first line in the file (`"Author","Quote"`) and `shuf -n1` picks one random line.

The second example again, but using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r author quote
do
    author="${author%\"}" # remove first "
    author="${author#\"}" # remove last "
    printf "%s\n\t~ %s\n" "$quote" "$author"
done < <(shuf -n1 <(tail -n +2 quotes.csv))
```

Comment: the second solution worked like a charm + its so clean!! thank you so much for all your help :)

Comment: ooops no not a problem at all! in fact, i had an 'old' tab open where i hadn't accepted your answer yet and thought the tick didn't go through! should be fixed now